# Dismiss vertical scrollview with swipe down

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that pops up when a button is clicked. I'd like to dismiss it when the screen is swiped down but the scrollview eats all the swipes.

I thought it may be possible to do this by disabling scrolling up when at the top of the scrollview but nothing I found worked with swift 3.

Please show me how to do that or let me know if there's a better way.

Comment: This link has solution for your kind of problem.. hiding view when reached to bottom : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014381/ios-switch-between-dismiss-and-scroll-gestures

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `UIPercentDrivenInteractionTransition`.

This answer has a great example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35205596/4371741