# Handling scroll views with (custom, interactive) view controller presentation and dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have been experimenting with custom interactive view controller presentation and dismissal (using a combination of `UIPresentationController`, `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`, `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`) and have mostly gotten things working well for my needs.

However, there is one common scenario that I've yet to find addressed in any of the tutorials or documentation that I've read, leading me to the following question:

...

**What is the proper way of handling custom interactive view controller dismissal, via a pan gesture, when the dismissed view contains a UIScrollView (ie. UITableView, UICollectionView, WKWebView, etc)?**

...

Basically, what I'd like is for the following:

1. View controllers are interactively dismissible by panning them down. This is common UX in many apps.
2. If the dismissed view controller contains a (vertically-scrolling) scroll view, panning down scrolls that view as expected until the user reaches the top, after which the scrolling ceases and the pan-to-dismiss occurs.
3. Scroll views should otherwise behave as normal.

I know that this is *technically* possible - I've seen it in other apps, such as Overcast and Apple's own Music app - but I've not been able to find the key to coordinating the behavior of my pan gesture with that of the scroll view(s).

Most of my own attempts center on trying to conditionally enable/disable the scrollview (or its associated pan gesture recognizer) based on its `contentOffset.y` while scrolling and having the view controller dismissal's pan gesture recognizer take over from there, but this has been fraught with problems and I fear that I am overthinking it.

I feel like the secret mostly lies in the following pan gesture recognizer delegate method:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
   // ...
}
```

I have created a reduced sample project which should demonstrate the scenario more clearly. Any code suggestions are highly welcome!

https://github.com/Darchmare/SlidePanel-iOS

Answer (score 26):

## Solution

- Make `scrollView` stop scrolling after it reached top by using [UIScrollView's bounces property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces) and [scrollViewDidScroll(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll) method.

  ```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      scrollView.bounces = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 10);
  }
  ```

  Don't forget to set `scrollView.delegate = self`
- Only handle `panGestureRecognizer` when `scrollView` reached top - It means when `scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0` by using a protocol.

  ```
  protocol PanelAnimationControllerDelegate {
      func shouldHandlePanelInteractionGesture() -> Bool
  }
  ```

  *ViewController*

  ```
  func shouldHandlePanelInteractionGesture() -> Bool {
      return (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0);
  }
  ```

  *PanelInteractionController*

  ```
  class PanelInteractionController: ... {

    var startY:CGFloat = 0

    private weak var viewController: (UIViewController & PanelAnimationControllerDelegate)?

    @objc func handlePanGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
      switch gestureRecognizer.state {
      case .began:
        break
      case .changed:
        let translation    = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: gestureRecognizer.view!.superview!)
        let velocity    = gestureRecognizer.velocity(in: gestureRecognizer.view!.superview)
        let state      = gestureRecognizer.state

        // Don't do anything when |scrollView| is scrolling
        if !(viewController?.shouldHandlePanelInteractionGesture())! && percentComplete == 0 {
          return;
        }

        var rawProgress    = CGFloat(0.0)

        rawProgress    = ((translation.y - startTransitionY) / gestureRecognizer.view!.bounds.size.height)

        let progress    = CGFloat(fminf(fmaxf(Float(rawProgress), 0.0), 1.0))

        if abs(velocity.x) > abs(velocity.y) && state == .began {
          // If the user attempts a pan and it looks like it's going to be mostly horizontal, bail - we don't want it... - JAC
          return
        }

        if !self.interactionInProgress {
          // Start to pan |viewController| down
          self.interactionInProgress = true
          startTransitionY = translation.y;
          self.viewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
          // If the user gets to a certain point within the dismissal and releases the panel, allow the dismissal to complete... - JAC
          self.shouldCompleteTransition = progress > 0.2

          update(progress)
        }
      case .cancelled:
        self.interactionInProgress = false
        startTransitionY = 0

        cancel()
      case .ended:
        self.interactionInProgress = false
        startTransitionY = 0

        if self.shouldCompleteTransition == false {
          cancel()
        } else {
          finish()
        }
      case .failed:
        self.interactionInProgress = false
        startTransitionY = 0

        cancel()
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

## Result

[image: enter link description here]

For more detail, you can take a look at [my sample project](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/panel-presentation)

Comment: Thats very clean approach to handle scrollView with panGesture.

Comment: So clean and understandable :)

Comment: work as a charm

Answer (score 1):

For me, this little bit of code answered a lot of my issues and greatly helped my custom transitions in scrollviews, it will hold a negative scrollview offset from moving while trying to start a transition or showing an activity indicator on the top. My guess is that this will solve at least some of your transition/animation hiccups:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -75 {

        scrollView.contentInset.top = -scrollView.contentOffset.y

    }
    // Do animation or transition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need an additional pan gesture recognizer to implement this. You can simply hook onto the different delegate methods of the scroll view to achieve the "pan to dismiss" effect. Here is how I went about it

```
// Set the dragging property to true
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_: UIScrollView) {
    isDragging = true
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // If not dragging, we could make an early exit
    guard isDragging else {
        return
    }

    let topOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y + statusBarHeight

// If The dismissal has not already started and the user has scrolled to the top and they are currently scrolling, then initiate the interactive dismissal
    if !isDismissing && topOffset <= 0 && scrollView.isTracking {
        startInteractiveTransition()
        return
    }

    // If its already being dismissed, then calculate the progress and update the interactive dismissal animator 
    if isDismissing {
        updateInteractiveTransitionProgress()
    }
}

// Once the scroll ends, check for a few things
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    // Early return   
    if !isDismissing {
        return
    }
    
    // Optional check to dismiss the controller, if swiped from the top
    checkForFastSwipes()
    
    // If dragged enough, dismiss the controller, otherwise cancel the 
       transition 
    if interactor?.shouldFinish ?? false {
        interactor?.finish()
    } else {
        interactor?.cancel()
    }
     
    // Finally reset the transition properties
    resetTransitionProperties()
}

private func checkForFastSwipes() {
    let velocity = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: view)
    let velDiff = velocity.y - velocity.x
    if velDiff > 0 && velDiff >= 75 {
        interactor?.hasStarted = false
        self.dismiss()
        interactor?.shouldFinish = true
    }
}

private func startInteractiveTransition() {
    isDismissing = true
    interactor?.hasStarted = true
    dismiss()
}

private func updateInteractiveTransitionProgress() {
    progress = max(
        0.0,
        min(1.0, ((-scrollView.contentOffset.y) - statusBarHeight) / 90.0)
    )
    interactor?.shouldFinish = progress > 0.5
    interactor?.update(progress)
}

private func resetTransitionProperties() {
    isDismissing = false
    isDragging = false
}
```

The interactor property used for synchronizing the animation with gesture

```
var interactor: Interactor?
class Interactor: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {
    var hasStarted = false
    var shouldFinish = false
}
```

Inspired by the following Kodeco tutorial 
https://www.kodeco.com/books/ios-animations-by-tutorials/v6.0/chapters/25-uiviewpropertyanimator-view-controller-transitions 
(Look for the *Interactive view controller transitions* section)

**Edit**

After implementing the solution below, I realized that it only works if you have sufficient content to scroll, however, if you have dynamic content wherein the contents are not guaranteed to be scrollable as was my case, you'd be better off adding a pan gesture as mentioned by @trungduc. However, there are a few improvements that we could make to their answer like detecting an upwards scroll and not letting it interfere with our gesture.

Under the changed state add the following code

```
let isUpwardsScroll = self.velocity(in: target).y < 0  
/* 
 If the user is normally scrolling the view, ignore it. However, 
 once the interaction starts allow such gestures as they could be  
 dragging the interactable view back
*/
if isUpwardScroll && !interactor.hasStarted {
   return
}
```