# Replicating iOS modal card UIScrollView dismiss behavior

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

iOS does magic when you're using default modal presentation for view controller with `UIScrollView` (or any its subclass like `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`) inside. One can dismiss presented modal by swiping down without triggering UIScrollView pan gesture recognizer events.

Is there a way to recreate such functionality while using custom presentation for bottom sheet functionality? I've tried using `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` but it always interferes with `UIScrollView`'s pan gesture recognizer.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011682/handling-scroll-views-with-custom-interactive-view-controller-presentation-an?rq=2) describes the same problem and has a solution but it looks different from native modal presentation because of turning off bouncing.